# Compiling Apache 2.4.9 with session cookie module

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

I compiled my Apache build with following configurations:

```
./configure \ 
    --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 \ 
    --sysconfdir=/etc/apache2 \ 
    --enable-so \ 
    --enable-info \ 
    --enable-session \ 
    --enable-session-cookie \ 
    --enable-lua \ 
    --enable-luajit \ 
    --enable-proxy \ 
    --enable-mods-shared=all \ 
    --with-included-apr
make
sudo make install
```

After completion of the above processes, when I try to start my server

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

I receive the following error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 136 of `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`: Cannot
>   load `modules/mod_session_cookie.so` into server:
>   `/usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_session_cookie.so`: undefined symbol:
>   `ap_hook_session_save`

On checking the **`httpd.conf`** file, I see the following:

```
135 #LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
136 LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
137 LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
```

where the number depict the line number in file. On uncommenting line #**135** and attempting again displays:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

which I think is OK. But the server still hasn't started.

---

`apachectl -V` gives:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr 13 2014 22:48:17
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:31
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Compiled using: APR 1.5.0, APR-UTIL 1.5.3
Architecture:   32-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache2/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was unrelated to my compile settings. The server wasn't starting because the following statement was commented in my `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
```

Uncommenting the above solved the issue.

Comment: hello what is problem in httpd.conf ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi The `socache..` module wasn't being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting the line:

```
LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
```

is solving the issue. @httpd-2.4.38

mod_session_cookie.so and mod_socache_shmcb.so can still be loaded if mod_session.so is active in httpd.conf